# size of intersection of 2 languages size is not decidable

Tags: turing-machines, reductions

I think that the next language is not decidable but I can't think of reduction to show it.
I would appreciate some hint or intuition

$EQ = $ { $<M1,M2>$ |$ M1\,\,\, and\,\,\, M2 \,\,\, are\,\,\, TMs\,\,\, and\,\,\, |\,L(M1)\,∩\,L(M2)\,|\, $$= 2020\, $}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider an instance of Halting problem $\langle M, x \rangle$. Construct a new Turing Machine which $M_x$ which will accept the strings $0$, $00$, $000 \ldots 0^{2020}$ if the machine $M$ halts on the input $x$; and it will reject all other strings. Let $M_u$ be the TM which accepts all the strings.

Convince yourself that $|L(M_x) \cap L(M_u)|$ will be 2020 if $M$ halts on $x$, and otherwise $0$.

The proof follows easily.

(Informal) Hint: Whenever you have such a question, try thinking about how can you solve the Halting problem (or some other undecidable language) using the *hypothetical* decider for the given language.

Comment: thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

welcome to the site :)

I assume you already know that the Halting problem $L_H$ is undecidable (as it is usually the first specific undecidable language students learn of).
So, let us try and find a reduction $L_H \leq EQ$.

We want to know whether some given TM $M$ halts given the input word $w$ by transforming the pair $\langle M, w \rangle$ to some $EQ$-instance $f(\langle M, w \rangle) = \langle M_1, M_2 \rangle$ such that $\langle M, w \rangle \in L_H$ if and only if $\langle M_1, M_2 \rangle \in EQ$.
Let us consider some dummy TM $M_{2020}$ which just accepts 2020 inputs (any set of 2020 words will do the trick) and modify $M_{2020}$ such that it only ever accepts if $M$ halts on $w$ to get another TM $M_{2020}(M, w)$.
Since we know $M$ and $w$ when we construct $M_{2020}(M, w)$, we can implement it to do the following:

1. Read the input and if it is one of the 2020 words accepted by $M_{2020}$, make note of that (we can use the states to store this).
2. Clear the tape and write $w$ to it.
3. Run $M$ on $w$.
4. If $M$ halts on $w$, accept the original input.

Such a construction can be performed by another TM, this is a bit tedious to show formally but by noting that we can essentially "embed" $M$ in $M_{2020}(M, w)$ it should be intuitive that this can be done (as $M_{2020}$ is a *fixed* TM).

Now observe that $M_{2020}(M, w)$ accepts some input $x \in L(M_{2020})$ precisely when $M$ halts on $w$, hence we have that $L(M_{2020}) = L(M_{2020}(M, w))$ if and only if $\langle M, w \rangle \in L_H$, otherwise we have $L(M_{2020}(M, w)) = \emptyset$.
It follows that 
$$
| L(M_{2020}(M, w)) \cap L(M_{2020}) | = 
 \begin{cases}
  2020, & \text{if $M$ halts on $w$} \\
  0, & \text{otherwise}
 \end{cases}
$$
and thus (denoting $\langle M_{2020}, M_{2020}(M, w) \rangle$ as $f(\langle M, w \rangle$) we have $\langle M, w \rangle \in L_H \Leftrightarrow f(\langle M, w \rangle)$ and therefore a suitable reduction.

An easier way to prove that the language is not decidable is by using [Rice's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem) which (roughly speaking) says that properties of functions computed by TMs (we call these *semantic* properties) cannot be decided algorithmically unless they are trivial.
If we fix some TM $M_1$ and consider an arbitrary TM $M$ then asking whether $L(M_1) \cap L(M)$ has size 2020 is such a semantic property and hence Rice's theorem immediately gives us that $EQ$ is undecidable.
The theorem (for me, at least) is basically the formal underpinning of the informal intuition I gave above.

Comment: wow thanks!!! well explained